# UINavbar frame initially 20px lower & but moves up once a user taps on the screen

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uipageviewcontroller

When using UINavigationBar in a Child View Controller, why is the frame initially 20px lower & thus separated from the Status Bar but fixed once a user taps on the screen

[image: Image of problem]

Comment: How do you add your child view controller? This is likely a bug in Apple's layout implementation.

Comment: [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];

Solved partially by removing the hidden uinavigationcontroller